# What is the purpose of git stash create and git stash store?

Tags: git, git-stash

From the documentation at [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), there are two git stash commands that mention relevance to scripting, but not general use:

> **create**
>
> Create a stash (which is a regular commit object) and return its object name, without storing it anywhere in the ref namespace. This is intended to be useful for scripts. It is probably not the command you want to use; see "save" above.
>
> **store**
>
> Store a given stash created via git stash create (which is a dangling merge commit) in the stash ref, updating the stash reflog. This is intended to be useful for scripts. It is probably not the command you want to use; see "save" above.

Supposing that we are considering the context of automated scripts, what advantages do `git stash create` and `git stash store` give me over the usual `git stash save` and friends?

Comment: Fun fact: `git stash create` gives no output when no local changes exist to stash, unlike `git stash save`.

Comment: I hope somebody answers this because it's something that I'm completely baffled by as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `git stash create` when you're writing scripts that need to stash as an implementation detail and you don't want to disturb the user's stash reflog.

Depending on what happens next, you might (in the case of error, say) decide you do want to disturb the stash reflog after all, at which point you can use `git stash store`.

Obviously a regular stash can be implemented in terms of `create` then `store`, but I can also imagine it being used in a hypothetical `update-branch` command that does something like this:

```
git stash create
git fetch
git rebase
git stash apply
```

Comment: Interesting, so it seems to have the advantage of not disturbing the stash reflog in the first stage.  Odd, to be sure.

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately the nice example that Andrew showed above does not work in all cases, because:

- If there **are** local changes then `git stash create` will create an unreferenced commit, but it won't actually clear the local changes.
- If there **are not** any local changes, then it won't create a commit at all (as BlackVegetable pointed out).  In that case we should not `apply` at the end.
- (And minor: Andrew forgot to keep and use the commit ID produced by `create`.)

With that in mind, it appears to me that the usage should be like this:

```sh
# Save the local changes, keep a reference to them, and clear them
stashed_commit="$(git stash create)"
git reset --hard

# Do your thing
git fetch
git rebase

# If there were local changes, then restore them
if [ -n "${stashed_commit}" ]
then git stash apply "${stashed_commit}"
fi
```

Unwieldy to say the least!

Alas.  It would be far simpler if I could just `git stash save --allow-empty` at the top, and `git stash pop` at the bottom.

*I would love to be wrong.  Please correct me!*

Comment: Note that in the specific case of a *rebase* we can actually just use `git rebase --autostash` to automatically do what we are doing above.

Comment: @torek `git stash create` doesn't remove the things that it stashed. `git stash save` _does_, but it is harder to tell whether it actually stashed anything or not (no error code, grepping the message would be fragile). Also with `create` we don't touch the stash stack at all, which has pros and cons.

Comment: Ah, huh, that's interesting. Does `git stash store` do the reset?  Well, it's a shell script, I'll go look... answer: no, only `git stash save` and `git stash push` do the reset, using `git reset --hard -q` unless paths were specified. Anyway, I'll delete the incorrect comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023) clarifies the role of `git stash store` in relationship with `git stash create`:

Feeding "[`git stash store`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/626f689f7903b51342cf31ad3792ba5e9e41586d/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L150)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-store))</sup> with a random commit that was not created by [`git stash create`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/626f689f7903b51342cf31ad3792ba5e9e41586d/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L142)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create))</sup> now errors out.

See [commit d9b6634](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5) (11 Oct 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 626f689](https://github.com/git/git/commit/626f689f7903b51342cf31ad3792ba5e9e41586d), 23 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5): be careful what we store

> "[`git stash store`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L150)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-store))</sup> is meant to store what [`git stash create`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L142)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create))</sup> produces, as these two are implementation details of the end-user facing "[`git stash save`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L66)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-save-p%7C--patch-S%7C--staged-k%7C--no-keep-index-u%7C--include-untracked-a%7C--all-q%7C--quietltmessagegt))</sup> command.
> Even though it is clearly documented as such, users would try silly things like "`git stash store`" HEAD to render their stash unusable.
>
> Worse yet, because "[`git stash drop`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L138)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-drop-q%7C--quietltstashgt))</sup> does not allow such a stash entry to be removed, "[`git stash clear`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9b6634589d5c59b49fd2fc41953469173a40ff5/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L133)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-clear))</sup> would be the only way to recover from such a mishap.
> Reuse the logic that allows "drop" to refrain from working on such a stash entry to teach "store" to avoid storing an object that is not a stash entry in the first place.

The error message:

```
store called with non-stash commit
```